# Error Connecting to Database: Access denied for user 'cats'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have created a database with the following users: `'auc'@'%'`, `'auc'@'localhost'`, and `'root'@127.0.0.1'`, `'root'@'::1'` and `'root'@'localhost'`.
But when I try to connect to the WAMP project, it denies me access to the database with the message:

> Error Connecting to Database Access denied for user 'cats'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

But I do not have in my users list the user 'cats', can anyone help me with these problems:
* the user issue (a user that I cannot find in my users list)
** how to allow access to the project

Thanks

Comment: Check your config file, user cats may be their in config or credential file. Which Framework u using for your project?

Comment: Searching your project for `cats` didn't yield any results?

Comment: 'cats' is provided somewhere in configs of your project (or source files). Just search for it in project sources

Comment: If we need to guess, see also [mysqli.default_user](http://php.net/mysqli.default-user), [mysqli.default_pw](http://php.net/mysqli.default-pw) and others.

Comment: I have 173 occurrences to go through. I will get back to you when I am through.

Comment: Kool-Mind: The project is OpenCats (opens source project).

Comment: hope this will help you... https://tech2smooth.blogspot.com/2014/09/create-mysql-user-and-grant-permission.html

Comment: The problem that I have is that the user is not 'cats'@'localhost' but is 'root':        mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

Comment: @Kool-Mind: How can the access be denied to 'cats'@'localhost' when I am connected to mysql with the user 'root'?

Comment: @Afedan Because your application tries to connect with a user `cats` that you don't have. It doesn't matter with what **other** programs you have successfully connected to your DB.

Comment: @Afedan it was config issue which you corrected given by yogesh

Answer (score 0):

As per OpenCats (opens source project) https://github.com/opencats/OpenCATS

config.php has followings constants defined,

```
/* Database configuration. */
define('DATABASE_USER', 'cats');
define('DATABASE_PASS', 'password');
define('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE_NAME', 'cats_dev');
```

I guess you suppose to make changes here as well.

Comment: Thank you Yogesh!

Answer (score 0):

The default username and password are offered in the setup wizard, but if you overrtype them with what you want, I.e. username auc then thats what will be written into config.php

I'm struggling to see how you could complete the setup wizard if you didn't already do this. But you're there now which is what matters.

Finally, there's an active support forum at forums.OpenCATS.org if you run into further problems.

RussH

Comment: Thanks, I have gone past this obstacle, but I am facing another problem that I have shared in OpenCats.org forum. Best!